# How do we achieve private class members in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am a Java developer trying my hands on Javascript. I understand that there are differences between the two. We can bind the data together using object, prototype or class(ES6). But how can we achieve private class members in Javascript like in Java?

For example I have a Cat class defined like:

```
function Cat() {
    this.name = "kitty";
    this.colour = "white";
}

var kitty = new Cat();
```

I don't want the name and colour attributes of the class to be accessible from outside the Cat declaration.

Is there any way to achieve this in Javascript?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. This is currently off topic without effort and code

Comment: How do classes/objects not achieve that…?

Comment: From what I understand of what you're asking, it seems you're simply looking to see if data encapsulation and public/private/protected status are available in javascript. Not in the same way as in java (i.e., explicitly via those terms), but yes. http://www.apress.com/us/book/9781590599082 goes into depth about how to do so, as do any number of professional javascript resources.

Comment: Are you thinking like interfaces and enums?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encapsulation in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329837/encapsulation-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a private member is possible in javascript. Although javascript doesn't support public,private attributes.

There are various ways of accomplishing it eg:closure(Already explained in above example) and various design patterns.

One of them is Modular Reveal Pattern, it goes like:

```
function Cat(){
  // PRIVATE MEMBERS
  var name = 'kitty';
  var color = 'white';
  var eats = function(){ return true };
  // PUBLIC MEMBERS (REVEALED MEMBERS)
  return {
    'catName':name,
    'catEats':eats
  }
}
var catInstance = new Cat();
console.log(catInstance.catName); //kitty (public)
console.log(catInstance.color); //undefined (private)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite believe that I'm about to quote Spiderman but …

> With great power comes great responsibility

JavaScript is powerful and flexible and gives programmers lots of freedom. It doesn't come with features designed to stop programmers writing bad code. When you write JavaScript, you are responsible for making sure the code is good, not the language.

Private variables/properties can be achieved using closures.

> Closures are functions that refer to independent (free) variables
>   (variables that are used locally, but defined in an enclosing scope).
>   In other words, these functions 'remember' the environment in which
>   they were created.

```
var add = (function () {
    var counter = 0; /// here is your private property/variable
    return function () {return counter += 1;}
})();

add();
add();
add();

// the counter is now 3
```

To learn more about Closures goto [clousers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

*Thanks!
Stay hungry, Stray foolish :)*